does reduceByKey() create a new job?
I am a newbie to spark and I have written a simple word which filters few stop words from the file, changes all to lower case , then uses reduceByKey to count occurrences, sortBy to sort by number of occurrences , take to see the top 10.
I have opened the spark UI and I see 3 jobs created , I am sure that take creates a job and I don't understand why I got the rest 2 jobs ,
I cannot post the code and screenshots of UI because it;s my assignment
Thank you.
b1=sc.textFile('./input_books/b1.txt')
b2=sc.textFile('./input_books/b2.txt')

def top25RepeatedWordFinder(path_to_file):
    b1=sc.textFile(path_to_file)
    b1=b1.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda a:a.lower()).map(clean_word)
    stopwords=[..list of stopwords..]
    b1=b1.filter(lambda a:a.lower() not in stopwords)
    b1=b1.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
    combined_books=b1.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
    sorted_combined_books=combined_books.sortBy(lambda x: x[1], ascending=False)
    print(sorted_combined_books.take(25))

top25RepeatedWordFinder('./input_books/b1.txt')

why does it create 3 jobs ?


If you post a sample code replicating your code it il be helpful.

FYI, reducebyKey() is a wide transformation which creates new Stage and not job.

Action directly proportional to Job (1 Action = 1 Job)

If you read the data from a file -> It is an Action.
If you use "inferSchema" -> It is an Action.
The show method -> It is an action.

@sumanth kumar can you post some dummy code that shows us what you're doing without posting things specific to the assignment?

@ArudSekaBerneS can you please check ! I have added the sample code

@DerekO I have posted the code, can you please check it !
